# understanding a program plan

Tags: c#

I am following a tutorial for learning C# and we are now creating a sample project, The project plan has been written where I am at right now, and it has an if statement (its code but not with the right syntax since its just the plan)

```
if empGrade >= 5 , budget += 150k
if empGrade < 5 , budget += 100k
```

Now the plan also has all the employees and their grades here is the plan:

[image: Sample project plan]

My question is if `budget += 150k` is the same as `budget = budget + 150k/100k` then why are the department budgets in the middle column only adding 50k once when they really should be adding it every time due to the if statement saying in layman terms every time an employee with a grade higher than 5 or lower than 5 is available add to the budget, 50k + 150/100k.

Comment: you should add how you put things thus with which empgrade it is called in which order

Comment: You need to add the code where it is happening! Its difficult to understand at present!

Comment: Becasue it is the starting budget.

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of this pseudo-jibberish.

Comment: Guys I haven't programmed the project yet that is why the beginning of the question states " we are now creating " implying I haven't actually made any progress on it just confused on the budget part

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with C# then? It seems just simple math to me.

Comment: It sounds like you're not adding anything at all seeing as the base budget is already 50k. You're going to need to show some code of how you have interpreted this diagram.

Comment: yes it does because I didn't understand why how the += operator was working and now I do since Gaz Winter explained

Comment: uhm if you don't have any code written so far then your statment is quite incorrect: "My question is if budget += 150k/100k is the same as budget = budget + 150k/100k then why are the department budgets in the middle column only adding 50k once when they really should be adding it every time due to the if statement saying in layman terms every time an employee with a grade "  that says that you already programmed it and it does the wrong thing

Comment: @Thomas no I am following a tutorial, the plan is not my plan it was formulated by the person who made the video (Patrick Washington) I was referring to the plans Middle column in which he highlights the budget in yellow boxes and has written the working out . At first I didn't understand how he got those answers but Gaz has explained it in his answer below

Comment: @NafisRahman what I meant was that your question was a bit confusing there as it sounded like you already wrote something and the code had the problem. That is also probably part of why you gathered that many downvotes as many ppl probably thought the same and thought that you didn't post code there. That you just had problems with interpreting/understanding the plan was not coming over there easily. Just something that you should take a look at if you have another planing problem in the future to make it clear that it is just the plan you are talking about and not the program itself.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the advice ill keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: no problem that is why I mention it. The clearer things are the easier it is to get help (had to learn it myself here in the beginning on how to best do questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not saying to add 50k each time.

The starting budget is £50k. Then for each employee it adds either an extra £100k or £150k to the cumulative total depending on their employee grade.

So in the example above it adds two employees to the XYZ IT.

One grade 7 (150k) and one grade 4 (100k).

So the maths is:

Starting budget
50k

Employee 1 added
50k + 150k = 200k

Employee 2 added
200k + 100k = 400k

Comment: Thanks for working with it although it may have been hard to understand due to being in pseudo, you really made it easy to understand. Budget is equal to 200k after employee 1 and then gets processed through employee 2

Answer (score 0):

50k is the starting budget!

For the first example, 450k would be right. The budget is 50K, then you add 2 x 150k for Alex & Linda, who are both above grade 5, then another 100k for John, who is below grade 5.

For the second example, the budget starts with 50k again, then you add 150k for Sara, who is above grade 5, and 100k for James, who is below grade 5.

Answer (score 0):

The 50k budget is a "fixed budget", even if there is nobody in the department, you have this budget. You don't add this every time you have a `if` statement, the `if` just add the new employee grade budget (that's why you use +=).

```
(start) budget = 50k

new budget = old budget + 150k/100k
new budget = 50k + 150k/100k
```